# Cordova camera doesn't let to use both camera and library to upload photo

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, camera, cordova-plugins, ionic-view

Is it possible to make Cordova Camera plugin use both options - camera and photo library? From Spec I see, that it depends on `sourceType` property which can indicates either camera or library, but not both at the same time.

If it's impossible to do via Cordova Camera plugin, are any other solutions? Will appreciate any help! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

take a look at this.hope it helps you  [cordova-camera-plugin-sample](http://sourcefreeze.com/cordova-camera-plugin-example-using-ionic-framework/)

Comment: It's a really nice article, but in the example actually there are two buttons - one for taking a photo with Camera, another for choosing it from Library. I was curious is is possible to combine taking a photo and choosing existed one in one button click. I am using `sourceType: Camera.PictureSourceType.PHOTOLIBRARY ` but still see an option "Take photo" and can open Camera. It's a bit confusing. So, why not to combine? Anyway, thank you for answering!